# Retorno de método com throw

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, exceção, throw

Este método tem o tipo de retorno `Connection`, porém nos blocos `catch` não existe um `return conn` e ainda sim não há erro de compilação ou execução. Acredito que seja pelo `throws` e `throw` mas não sei exatamente o porque.

```
    public static Connection getConexao() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER_CONEXAO);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(STR_CONEXAO + DATABASE, USUARIO, SENHA);

        return conn;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(
                "Driver MySql não foi encontrado " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException("Erro ao conectar "
                + "com a base de dados" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Se caiu no `catch`, quer dizer que ocorreu algum problema e a ação dentro do `try` não foi executada, por isso a exceção é lancada. Se não criou a conexão por algum motivo, como você vai cria-la? A finalidade da exceção é essa, informar qual problema ocorreu e onde ocorreu para que você possar corrigir posteriormente.

Comment: E outra, relançar exceção de conexão em diante não é uma boa pratica. Ou você cria uma exceção personalizada para passar a mensagem do erro em diante ou lança(creio que essa opção seja um pouco "porca") como uma `RunTimeException ` e trata mais em diante para que a mensagem seja exibida de forma amigável. Outra coisa, não faz muito sentido colocar try/catch e colocar throws para as mesmas exceções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É pela suposição que está na pergunta e também porque está lançando outra exceção (o que é incomum e provavelmente algo errado a fazer). Se uma exceção é lançada, o `return` não é necessário. Se você tirar esta exceção, nem compila.

[Veja o exemplo "executando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R3KDFh). E [veja nem compilando](https://ideone.com/5cvsNv). [Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/ThrowExample.java).

De qualquer forma se isso não é apenas um exemplo, é a forma errada de usar exceção. Leia sobre o assunto na *tag* [exceção](/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Tem inúmeras perguntas sobre o assunto onde, eu e outros usuários aqui falam sobre o jeito certo de usar exceções, e como a maioria dos programadores usam de forma errada.

Comment: Relançar é errado? Mas eu costumo relançar uma exceção customizada quando ocorre erro com o banco e tratar o problema na própria classe, porque minhas classes views e controllers não precisam saber o que fazer com uma exceção que é de responsabilidade da classe de conexão. Não esta linha de raciocínio a se seguir: cada classe com sua responsabilidade?

Comment: Sim, é errado na maioria das situações. Em Java nem tanto porque ela abusa de exceções, então tem muitos casos, não tem outro jeito. Você perde informações da pilha e acha que o erro está em um lugar diferente do que realmente está. É claro que para tudo tem exceção (com o perdão do trocadilho). Cada classe com sua responsabilidade, claro. Tem casos onde é ok fazer isto, você parece saber disto. Este exemplo específico da pergunta é que está errado e você já observou isto no seu comentário.

Comment: Entendi, você se referia a problemas como o da pergunta, não de forma generalizada na linguagem, creio que houve um equivoco na minha interpretação.

Comment: Também tem problemas generalizados sim, mas estava falando mais da pergunta.