# Qual a diferença entre throw e alert?

Tags: javascript, alert, throw

Nas funções abaixo verifico que o `throw` funciona igual ao `alert()`. Posso substituir ele por um `alert()`? Haveria algum inconveniente?

```js
var letters = new Array("A","B","C","D","E")
function getLetter(fld) {
     try {
           var inp = parseInt(fld.value, 10)
               if (isNaN(inp)) {
                    throw "Entry was not a number."
               }
               if (inp < 0 || inp > 4) {
                   throw "Enter only 0 through 4."
               }
               fld.form.output.value = letters[inp]
     }
     catch (e)  {
               alert(e)
               fld.form.output.value = ""
               fld.focus()
               fld.select()
     }
}
```

```html
<FORM>
Enter a number from 0 to 4: 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="input" SIZE=5>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get Letter" onClick=getLetter(this.form.input)>
Matching Letter is:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="output" SIZE=5>
</FORM>
```

Faço o mesmo código com `alert()` e funciona da mesma forma: para verificar digite um não numérico no `input()` em ambos os códigos

```js
var letters = new Array("A","B","C","D","E")
function getLetter(fld) {
     try {
           var inp = parseInt(fld.value, 10)
               if (isNaN(inp)) {
                    alert("Entry was not a number.")
               }
               if (inp < 0 || inp > 4) {
                   throw "Enter only 0 through 4."
               }
               fld.form.output.value = letters[inp]
     }
     catch (e)  {
               alert(e)
               fld.form.output.value = ""
               fld.focus()
               fld.select()
     }
}
```

```html
<FORM>
Enter a number from 0 to 4: 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="input" SIZE=5>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get Letter" onClick=getLetter(this.form.input)>
Matching Letter is:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="output" SIZE=5>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apenas por acaso tem o mesmo comportamento neste código específico. Na verdade isso nem é obrigatório, e de fato JavaScript não usado em um navegador mudará com certeza. Há zero relação entre eles.

O `alert()` é uma função presente no navegador para alertar de alguma coisa qualquer e está é a única capacidade dela. É algo da biblioteca e não tem maiores consequências na execução do código.

O `throw` é algo da linguagem, interfere fortemente na execução do código e desvia sua execução. Ele lembra um pouco um `return` porque ele encerra a execução ali e vai parar no primeiro `catch` que ele achar. Ele é um comando de controle de fluxo, mas que não deve ser usado para isto. Ele é útil em alguns casos para informar erro para outra parte desconhecida do código. Quando bem usado pode fazer o código ficar mais fácil de escrever e de lidar, se abusado pode ficar muito pior. Ele é um `goto` glorificado, portanto bem ruim, a não ser quando tem um motivo forte para seu uso que compense o problema que ele traz.

Quase sempre ter um `throw` diretamente onde tem um `catch` é um erro. Então nesse caso não faz sentido fazer isso, é claramente um caso para resolver no `if`.

Entendo que esse foi só um exemplo, mas já que está com dúvida do seu uso lembre-se que ele é inútil em código real.

E pra falar a verdade JS não tem muito a cultura de lançar exceções, isso acaba sendo bom, porque as pessoas acham bonitinho e abusam do seu uso. Tem muito material no site sobre o assunto.

Veja que se eu tirar o `alert()` do `catch` não faz a mesma coisa.

```js
var letters = new Array("A","B","C","D","E")
function getLetter(fld) {
    try {
        var inp = parseInt(fld.value, 10)
        if (isNaN(inp)) throw "Entry was not a number."
        if (inp < 0 || inp > 4) throw "Enter only 0 through 4."
        fld.form.output.value = letters[inp]
     } catch (e) {
        console.log("deu erro");
     }
}
```

```html
<FORM>
Enter a number from 0 to 4: 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="input" SIZE=5>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get Letter" onClick=getLetter(this.form.input)>
Matching Letter is:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="output" SIZE=5>
</FORM>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Catch.js).

E agora sem o `catch`:

```js
var letters = new Array("A","B","C","D","E")
function getLetter(fld) {
    var inp = parseInt(fld.value, 10)
    if (isNaN(inp)) throw "Entry was not a number."
    if (inp < 0 || inp > 4) throw "Enter only 0 through 4."
    fld.form.output.value = letters[inp]
}
```

```html
<FORM>
Enter a number from 0 to 4: 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="input" SIZE=5>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get Letter" onClick=getLetter(this.form.input)>
Matching Letter is:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="output" SIZE=5>
</FORM>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Catch2%2Cjs).

Então não tem como estabelecer qualquer relação entre essas duas coisas.

Conforme antecipei não é muito usado em JS e por isso tem pouco material, mas pode ver sobre exceções em outras linguagens que é muito parecido:

- [O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/101)
- [Retorno de método com throw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98068/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)
- [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)
- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)
- [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101)

Comment: "as pessoas acham bonitinho e abusam do seu uso". Tem razão. Eu acho bonitinho, mas evito por não saber usar bem o bastante.

Comment: @bfavaretto quase ninguém sabe, inclusive eu :D Mas claro que sei que ele é problemático, é um `goto` do pior jeito, você sequer sabe pra onde vai. Eu tenho até uma palestra chamada "Exceções: o goto do século XXI".

Comment: Entendi, `O throw é algo da linguagem, interfere fortemente na execução do código e desvia sua execução` fiz o seguinte teste: primeira condição ` if (inp == 0) {` segunda condição `if (inp < 1 || inp > 4) {` Nesse caso se entrar com o valor `0` e colocar  `alert` nas duas condições vai aparecer duas vezes, um para cada caso. Com `throw` para na primeira condição.

Comment: Sim, ele muda o fluxo. Mas tem várias formas de fazer isto, a exceção não deveria ser usada pra controlar o fluxo e sim facilitar quando o fluxo é complexo.

Comment: show de bola professor!!

Answer (score 11):

Na verdade a declaração `throw` **não funciona igual** ao `alert`, o que ela faz é lançar uma exceção definida pelo usuário, e tudo que tiver depois do `throw` não será executado. E o controle será passado para o primeiro bloco `catch`. No seu caso você tem um bloco `catch` e nele você chama o método `alert` passando o parâmetro `e` que é a exceção que você lançou usando o `throw`.

Se você for no seu bloco `catch` e comentar o método `alert` vai ver que nenhuma caixa de diálogo será aberta.

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade o que acontece é o seguinte:

- o `throw` lança um erro
- este erro é capturado pelo `catch`
- o `catch` chama `alert(e)`

Exemplo:

```js
try {
    throw "erro!";
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Será mostrado o `alert` com a mensagem do erro.

Mas isso não quer dizer que o `throw` funciona igual ao `alert`. Basta removermos o `alert` de dentro do `catch` para verificarmos isso:

```js
try {
    throw "erro!";
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Agora a mensagem de erro é mostrada no `console`, pois eu não estou mais chamando o `alert` dentro do `catch` (troquei por `console.log`).

Repare que nenhum `alert` foi mostrado, pois `throw` não funciona igual ao `alert`. Ele só lança o erro (que será capturado pelo `catch`).

---

O seu segundo exemplo está apenas chamando um `alert` dentro do `try`. Como nenhum erro é gerado neste caso, ele não entra no `catch`:

```js
try {
    alert("Entry was not a number.")
} catch(e) {
    alert("Não serei executado");
}
```

---

Resumindo, o `throw` só lança o erro, que será capturado pelo `catch`. No seu primeiro exemplo, experimente remover o `alert` que está dentro do `catch` para ver que nenhuma janela de `alert` será mostrada.